# The multi-part identifier "column name" could not be bound issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to pull data from 2 tables:

•   DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplier
•   DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType

Both columns have a common field & value `SupplierTypeCode`, hence the Join
But I want to see the Description column value from  `DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType` in the query

```
> Select                Supplier.SupplierNumber as [Dolfin Code]
>                      ,Supplier.SagesupplierCode as [Sage Code]
>                      ,Supplier.SupplierName as Name
>                      ,Supplier.PrimaryTel as Tel
>                      ,Supplier.PrimaryFax as Fax
>                      ,Supplier.PrimaryContact as Contact
>                      ,Supplier.SupplierTypeCode  as [Supplier Type] 
>                      ,DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType.Description as [Type Description]
>                      ,Supplier.Add1 as [Add 1]
>                      ,Supplier.Add2 as [Add 2]
>                      ,Supplier.Add3 as [Add 3]
>                      ,Supplier.Add4 as [Add 4]
>                      ,Supplier.CountryCode as Country
>                      ,Supplier.CurrencyCode as Currency
>                            FROM DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplier as Supplier,DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType as SupplierType
>                            full outer join DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType
>                            on DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplier.SupplierTypeCode =
> DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType.SupplierTypeCode
>                            where Deactivated=0
```

receiving the follwoing error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The multi-part identifier "DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplier.SupplierTypeCode" could not be bound.

I have tried using aliases in the Join without any success as below:

```
Full outer Join DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType as SupplierType ON SupplierType.SupplierTypeCode = Supplier.SupplierTypeCode
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins. Use explicit `JOIN` everywhere!

Comment: Explicit joins are evaluated before comma separated ones. This means that your FULL OUTER JOIN condition only has access to SupplierType and DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType columns.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not appropriate here.  The `WHERE` clause defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType` is used two times in the `FROM` clause. It can be mentioned in one time is enough. Also if you are apply table alias, then you can use the same in the `SELECT` statement too.

Can you try the query below:

```
SELECT              
 Supplier.SupplierNumber as [Dolfin Code]
 ,Supplier.SagesupplierCode as [Sage Code]
 ,Supplier.SupplierName as Name
 ,Supplier.PrimaryTel as Tel
 ,Supplier.PrimaryFax as Fax
 ,Supplier.PrimaryContact as Contact
 ,Supplier.SupplierTypeCode  as [Supplier Type] 
 ,SupplierType.Description as [Type Description]
 ,Supplier.Add1 as [Add 1]
 ,Supplier.Add2 as [Add 2]
 ,Supplier.Add3 as [Add 3]
 ,Supplier.Add4 as [Add 4]
 ,Supplier.CountryCode as Country
 ,Supplier.CurrencyCode as Currency
FROM DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplier AS Supplier
FULL OUTER JOIN DolfinRMSCum.dbo.tSupplierType AS SupplierType ON SupplierType.SupplierTypeCode = Supplier.SupplierTypeCode
WHERE Deactivated = 0
```

Comment: @Saleigh You're Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!